# AssignedTo Column multi users via REST-API

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, rest, user, ajax

Is it possible to set (Update/Create) 2 users to the AssignedTo column in SharePoint Online?

I am using REST-API (JS). When I put one user with:

> AssignedTo "- 1; #USER@company.com"

it works, but how do I add two or more users into the same item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you have to **Allow multiple selections** in `AssignedTo` column.

[image]

To add/update multi valued Person or Group column, you have to specify the `ID`'s of the Persons or Groups like

```
var data = {
    __metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.TestListItem" },
    Title: "Some title",
    AssignedToId: { 'results': [11,22] } 
}
```

You will find more in this [CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: thanks :) it worked
and I have found another way that works well
`AssignedTo " ; #ID ; #ID ; #ID "`

Comment: It is by default set to accept more than one person. I am trying and I keep getting a 400 error?