# unable to get value of a global variable

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, javascript, custom-form

I have created one function `GetUserInfo` which is calling another function `GetUserId`.

I want value of `txtAppArchitectId` variable to be stored globally so that I can access that after the function is called. But I am unable to retain its value due to some scope issue.

Please assist.

I have already declared `txtAppArchitectId` variable in `$(document).ready()`.

```
function getUserInfo(peoplePickerElementId) {
    try{            
        var toSpanKey = peoplePickerElementId+ "_TopSpan";
        var peoplePicker = null;

        var ClientPickerDict = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict;

        for (var propertyName in ClientPickerDict) {
             if (propertyName == toSpanKey) {
                  peoplePicker = ClientPickerDict[propertyName];
                  break;
             }
        }

        if (peoplePicker != null) {  
            // Get information about all users.
            var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
            var userInfo = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var user = users[i];
                for (var userProperty in user) { 
                    userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
                }
            }

            // Get user keys.
            var keys = peoplePicker.GetAllUserKeys();
            if(users[0].Key != null && users[0].Key != '')
            {
               // $('#userKeys').html(keys);
               var u=users[0].Key;
               // Get the first user's ID by using the login name.

                var x = getUserId(users[0].Key,peoplePickerElementId);
                alert(x[1]);
            }
        }
      }
      catch(err){}
 }


    // Get the user ID.
    function getUserId(loginName,peoplePickerElementId) {
        debugger;
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var user = context.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
        context.load(user);

        try
        {
        debugger;
             context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
              debugger;
             var pepuserid = peoplePickerElementId+"?"+ user.get_id();
                                var UniqueID = pepuserid.split("?")[1];

                                var UniquedivID = pepuserid.split("?")[0];

                                var RequestorDiv ='txtAppArchitect';

                                if(RequestorDiv == UniquedivID)
                                {
                                    txtAppArchitectId = UniqueID; 

                                    //alert("hello" +txtAppArchitectId);
                                }
            },  

            function(sender, args){      
              alert(args.get_message());         
            });
          }
        catch(err){}                                        
        return [deferred.promise(),txtAppArchitectId];                                                        
    }
```

Comment: @Ganesh i have declared the variable above now but still value is remaining in try block only. even no value is getting returned in return [deferred.promise(),txtAppArchitectId];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code as below.

```
function getUserInfo(peoplePickerElementId) {
    try{            
        var toSpanKey = peoplePickerElementId+ "_TopSpan";
        var peoplePicker = null;
        var ClientPickerDict = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict;
        for (var propertyName in ClientPickerDict) {
             if (propertyName == toSpanKey) {
                  peoplePicker = ClientPickerDict[propertyName];
                  break;
             }
        }
        if (peoplePicker != null) {  
            // Get information about all users.
            var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
            var userInfo = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var user = users[i];
                for (var userProperty in user) { 
                    userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
                }
            }
            // Get user keys.
            var keys = peoplePicker.GetAllUserKeys();
            if(users[0].Key != null && users[0].Key != '') {
               // $('#userKeys').html(keys);
               var u=users[0].Key;
               // Get the first user's ID by using the login name.

                var userId = getUserId(users[0].Key);
                alert(userId);
            }
        }
      }
      catch(err){}
}
function getUserId(loginName){
    var userId=-1;
    /// get the site url
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
    var payload = { 'logonName': loginName}; 
    /// make an ajax call to get the site user
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/ensureuser",
        method: "POST",
        async:false,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        headers: {
             "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
             "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            userId=data.d.Id;
        },
        error: function (data) {            
        }
    });
    return userId;
}
```

If you allow multiple users, modify the code as below.

```
function getUserInfo(peoplePickerElementId) {
    try{            
        var toSpanKey = peoplePickerElementId+ "_TopSpan";
        var peoplePicker = null;
        var ClientPickerDict = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict;
        for (var propertyName in ClientPickerDict) {
             if (propertyName == toSpanKey) {
                  peoplePicker = ClientPickerDict[propertyName];
                  break;
             }
        }
        if (peoplePicker != null) {  
            // Get information about all users.
            var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
            var userInfo = '';
            var userIds=[];
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var user = users[i];
                for (var userProperty in user) { 
                    userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
                }                
                var userId=GetUserId(users[i].Key);
                if(userId!=-1){
                    userIds.push(userId);
                }
            }
            alert(userIds.toString());           
        }
      }
      catch(err){}
}
```

Comment: it worked.. thanks @LZ_MSFT

Comment: do you have any idea how i can retreive those values now from list column using rest API. i am using below line but nothing is getting displayed in client peoplepicker div tag.  
  $("#txtApplicationArchitect").val(data.d.ApplicationArchitectID);

Comment: To get user field using REST API: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListTitle')/items?$select=ApplicationArchitect/Title,ApplicationArchitect/Id&$expand=ApplicationArchitect/Id". Refer to: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31210.sharepoint-2013-get-user-details-from-person-or-group-field-using-rest-api.aspx

Comment: Do you have idea on how to add multiple users into peoplepicker. i have set schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true; in intialize peoplepicker.But that is not working and telling only one value is allowed in peoplepicker field.

Comment: Check my updated reply.

Comment: yes it is working fine and user IDs are populating in array, but how to assign multiple values of array to list column? with one value it is working fine but storing multiple values(array) is giving error in Rest call.

Comment: The data like: var data = {
    __metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.TestListItem" },
    Title: "Some title",
    AssignedToId: { 'results': [11,22] } 
} , refer to: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167919/assignedto-column-multi-users-via-rest-api

Comment: the above code was working fine as long as i have SCA access. But not for contribure access people as it is using SiteAbsoluteURL(rootsite) in function getUserId(loginName) and we are writing the code in subsite where we are using webAbsoluteURL(subsite) and we are getting user not found/does not exist error. Please assist

Answer (score 0):

instead of $(document).ready() function, declare a variable above to it.

Example:

```
var txtAppArchitectId = "";
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Do your stuff
});
function getUserInfo(peoplePickerElementId) {
    try{            
        var toSpanKey = peoplePickerElementId+ "_TopSpan";
        var peoplePicker = null;

        var ClientPickerDict = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict;

        for (var propertyName in ClientPickerDict) {
             if (propertyName == toSpanKey) {
                  peoplePicker = ClientPickerDict[propertyName];
                  break;
             }
        }

        if (peoplePicker != null) {  
            // Get information about all users.
            var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
            var userInfo = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var user = users[i];
                for (var userProperty in user) { 
                    userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
                }
            }

            // Get user keys.
            var keys = peoplePicker.GetAllUserKeys();
            if(users[0].Key != null && users[0].Key != '')
            {
               // $('#userKeys').html(keys);
               var u=users[0].Key;
               // Get the first user's ID by using the login name.

                var x = getUserId(users[0].Key,peoplePickerElementId);
                alert(x[1]);
            }
        }
      }
      catch(err){}
 }


    // Get the user ID.
    function getUserId(loginName,peoplePickerElementId) {
        debugger;
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var user = context.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
        context.load(user);

        try
        {
        debugger;
             context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
              debugger;
             var pepuserid = peoplePickerElementId+"?"+ user.get_id();
                                var UniqueID = pepuserid.split("?")[1];

                                var UniquedivID = pepuserid.split("?")[0];

                                var RequestorDiv ='txtAppArchitect';

                                if(RequestorDiv == UniquedivID)
                                {
                                    txtAppArchitectId = UniqueID; 
                                    return [deferred.promise(),txtAppArchitectId];                                                        

                                    //alert("hello" +txtAppArchitectId);
                                }
            },  

            function(sender, args){      
              alert(args.get_message());         
            });
          }
        catch(err){}                                        
      }
```

Comment: I have declared the variable above now but still value is remaining in try block only. even no value is getting returned in return [deferred.promise(),txtAppArchitectId];

Comment: Can you change the return statement from bottom to the last line of this method context.executeQueryAsync

Comment: i changed the return statement but it is still returning empty variable as this is an async call in context.executeQueryAsync. Value of txtAppArchitectId is getting fetched later. Please assist

Comment: have you got the value in context.executeQueryAsync method (alert)?

Comment: Yes the value is comming in alert but after the async call . This is the commented line where i am getting the value inside context.executeQueryAsync 
         alert("hello" +txtAppArchitectId);

Comment: Did you get the value in txtAppArchitectId return statement

`if(RequestorDiv == UniquedivID)
                                {
                                    txtAppArchitectId = UniqueID; 
                                    return [deferred.promise(),txtAppArchitectId];                                                        

                                    //alert("hello" +txtAppArchitectId);
                                }`

Comment: no i am not getting the value in return statement in this case.

Comment: Use Async/Await for Caller/Calling methods